# Characteristic Method for linear equation

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm looking here for a reference to solve the following equation with the method of characteristic
$$ \partial_t U + A\partial_x U = f$$
$$U(t=0,x)=U_0(x)$$
$$B(t,x=0)U = 0$$
where $(t,x)\in [0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^+$, $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix with constant coefficient with $\det A\neq 0$ with positive eigenvalues and $B$ a $n\times n$ matrix with constant coefficient with $\det B \neq 0$. $f\in L^2((0,T)\times \mathbb{R}^+)$, $U_0\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)$.
Everywhere I look the characteristic method is developed for regular solutions.

Can anyone provide a clear reference for the method of characteristic with data in $L^2$ on this example (if possible) or for another example (where it gives the existence and the uniqueness of a solution)?

Comment: The proof of unicity even for a smooth initial data would be interesting for vector-valued functions. A little remark - in your case the boundary condition is equivalent to $U(t,0)=0$.

Comment: For this particular case it's a claim in the book of Denis Serre and Sylvie Benzoni-Gavage (it is supposed to be direct with the method of characteristic). Anyway, I'm looking for a reference on the characteristic method with data $L^2$.